# Allow app to create directory with Heroku (even temporary)

Tags: heroku

My app is throwing this error when run:

```
2019-07-25T12:00:43.847131+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: jetbrains.exodus.ExodusException: Failed to create directory: /mnt/xodus/master
2019-07-25T12:00:43.847132+00:00 app[web.1]: at jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataReaderWriterProvider$Companion.checkDirectory(FileDataReaderWriterProvider.kt:59)
```

It is unable to create a directory, what can be done as such my application can write file even temporary (meaning when app reloads data is deleted, that's okay)

Comment: What is `/mnt/xodus` supposed to be? What is it used for? Why is it in `/mnt`? This doesn't look like a regular temporary directory; it looks like a mountpoint for something.

Comment: In our current non-Heroku server it is a path to a mounted block storage device

Comment: Okay, but you can't have a mounted block storage device on Heroku. What are you using it for?

Comment: @Chris it is used to store database (data); not sure if I totally understand your question.

Comment: I don't think _`/mnt`_ even exists on Heroku, let alone `/mnt/xodus`. Why are you trying to put data _there_? It sounds like you're already familiar with Heroku's ephemeral filesystem?